# Segmentation Fault on input of string of size 1

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, palindrome

I am getting segmentation fault (core dumped) when i pass string of size 1 as input. I tried searching for the reason but i could not find any , i was asked to debug my program . From debugging i have realised that it throws segmentation fault on reading string of size 1.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ll t,x,y;
    string s;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        cin>>s;
        int tilt=0;
        for(int i=s.length()-1,j=0;i>=s.length()/2;i--,j++){
            if(s[i]!=s[j]){
                tilt = s[i]>s[j]?-1:1;
                s[i]=s[j];
            }
        }
        if(tilt==-1 || tilt==0){
            if(s.length()%2==0){
                y=1;x=s.length()/2-1;
                while(y!=0 && x>=0){
                    if(s[x]=='9'){
                        s[x]='0';
                    }else{
                        s[x] += 1;
                        y=0;
                    }
                    x--;
                }
                if(y==0){
                    for(int i=0;i<s.length()/2;i++){
                        cout<<s[i];
                    }
                    for(int i=s.length()/2-1;i>=0;i--){
                        cout<<s[i];
                    }
                    cout<<endl;
                }else{
                    cout<<1;
                    for(int i=0;i<s.length()/2;i++){
                        cout<<s[i];
                    }
                    for(int i=s.length()/2-2;i>=0;i--){
                        cout<<s[i];
                    }
                    cout<<1<<endl;
                }
            }else{
                y=1;x=s.length()/2;
                while(y!=0 && x>=0){
                    if(s[x]=='9'){
                        s[x]='0';
                    }else{
                        s[x] += 1;
                        y=0;
                    }
                    x--;
                }
                if(y==0){
                    for(int i=0;i<s.length()/2;i++){
                        cout<<s[i];
                    }
                    for(int i=s.length()/2;i>=0;i--){
                        cout<<s[i];
                    }
                    cout<<endl;
                }else{
                    cout<<1;
                    for(int i=0;i<s.length()/2;i++){
                        cout<<s[i];
                    }
                    for(int i=s.length()/2-1;i>=0;i--){
                        cout<<s[i];
                    }
                    cout<<1<<endl;
                }
            }
        }else{
            cout<<s<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input: 
1
11
Output:
22

Input:
1
1
Output:
Error

Question : https://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
for(int i=s.length()-1,j=0;i>=s.length()/2;i--,j++){
```

when `s` is of size 1, `s.length()/2` is an **unsigned** quantity with value 0. When comparing an integer with an unsigned, the integer is converted to an unsigned before the comparison. Checking if an unsigned value is >= 0 is always true, so this is an infinite loop. That's why it crashes.

I would hope that your compiler gives you warnings about the dangers of signed/unsigned comparisons.

Here's one way to fix this particular loop, but I'd guess you have similar problems elsewhere in your code.

```
for (size_t i = s.length(), j = 0; i > s.length()/2; ++j) {
    --i;
    if (s[i] != s[j]) {
        tilt = s[i] > s[j] ? -1 : 1;
        s[i] = s[j];
    }
}
```

Some advice

- Use `size_t` for index variables.
- When looping backwards be very careful about the termination condition, the way I do it is to make the variable one bigger than it needs to be and decrement it at the beginning of the loop instead of the end. That way you compare with `>` not `>=` and avoid the problem your code has.
- Try to use some spaces in your code. It makes it easier to read for everyone, including yourself.

Comment: Thanks for answer john , but even when i try to print an " * " before this for loop it fails . It never reaches the for loop.

Comment: @Ayush I don't see how that is possible, there are only a few lines of code before that loop, and none of them would cause a crash.    `ll t,x,y;
    string s;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        cin>>s;
        int tilt=0;
` Maybe you misunderstood which loop I was talking about?

Comment: @Ayush Also printing a `"*"` is not diagnostic. Output is buffered, so just because you don't see the `*` doesn't mean it hasn't been printed.You should print like this `cout << "*" << flush;` to make sure the output appears immediately (`cout << "*" << endl;` also works).

Comment: thank you very much , you are absolutely correct . I could have never figured it out on my own . Your instructions worked perfectly.